# html2canvas Error: No logger instance found

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I render with html2canvas and I seem to only get this error about 5% of the time when I render the exact same thing over and over again. Why do I get this error and why is it sporadic?

```
html2canvas.js:2396 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No logger instance found with id 170ae84309d
    at Function.Logger.getInstance (html2canvas.js:2396)
    at html2canvas.js:7003
    at step (html2canvas.js:83)
    at Object.next (html2canvas.js:64)
    at fulfilled (html2canvas.js:54)
Logger.getInstance  @   html2canvas.js:2396
```

I loop through a collection of divs and use this function to render the images I need:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#'+img.element_id), {dpi:300, scale: 2}).then(canvas => {      
  this[img.name] = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',1.0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the html2canvas.js file revealed a destroy function that must have been firing prematurely and the instance was deleted before the program was done with it. Once I commented that function everything worked perfectly 100% of the time.

```
//Logger.destroy(instanceName);
```